# Django - ForeignKey Add Users Value As Default

Tags: django, model, foreign-keys

I'd like to implement a grading model into my Django WebApp. This Grade Model has 3 ForeignKeys being a student, a subject and the schoolclass of the student. Is there a way to default the value of that field to student.klasse (which is already a field in the student model).

models.py

```
class Person(AbstractUser):  # called the model Person since they can be teacher or student
    klasse = models.ForeignKey(SchoolClass, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

class Test(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    school_class = models.ForeignKey(SchoolClass, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=student.klasse_id, blank=True, null=True)
```

It throws this Error when trying to make the migration:

```
school_class = models.ForeignKey(SchoolClass, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=student.klasse_id, blank=True, null=True)
AttributeError: 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'klasse_id'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it like this.
This code is runned at the class level, `student` is a `ForeignKey` object. This is different from an instance of `Test` where `my_test.student` is an object of type `Person`

To achieve what you're trying to do, i would override the [save()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) function of the `Test` model

```
class Test(models.Model)
    # Fields
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.school_class and self.student:
            self.school_class = self.student.klass
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Just be aware that this code will only run when doing `my_test.save()` or `Test.objects.create(...)`.
The default value will not be applied when calling `Test.objects.update(...)`, `Test.objects.bulk_create(...)` or inserting row directly in DB.

If you want the default value to be applied no matter what, you'll need take a look at the features provided by your DB system